# Java: Get all first entries from ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList (~900 entries) containing arrays of user information:

```
[swaschit, Sophia Waschitz, Dormant, Inactive, 1/1/2018]
[kolanday, Kyle Olanday, Dormant, Inactive, 1/1/2018]
[npowers, Neil Powers, Assigned, Active, 2/11/2018]
```

I want to generate an array from this list containing only the first elements of each object:

```
[swaschit, kolanday, npowers, ...]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Don't use arrays but create your own class `User` which has fields for `username`, `name`, `assignedState`, `activity` and `birthdate`

Comment: @Lino I am generating the list from a CSV file using CSVParser. Is there a way to  save the data into a custom class directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a `Stream` and `map` each of the inner arrays to its first element:

```
List<String> firstElements = yourList.stream()
                                     .map(x -> x[0].toString()) // you might need toString() here if your array is an Object[]
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you would like an array of strings instead:

```
String[] firstElements = yourList.stream()
                                     .map(x -> x[0].toString()) // you might need toString() here if your array is an Object[]
                                     .toArray(String[]::new);
```

I also suggest you to not use nested arrays like this. You should create a class with the properties you want to store and create a `List` of your class.

Comment: Since this is unchecked cast, better use toString method, which return `this` pointer, in case of String object

Comment: @МаксимГорбунов Edited.

Comment: @Sweeper the question was how to get an array, not a `List`. So a `.toArray(new String[0])` would be appropriate I think.

Answer (score 1):

As I suppose the first entry is unique (as it seems to be a username), I would suggest using a Map. That way, you could simply list the keys.

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hashmap=new HashMap<>();
```

Alternatively, you could simply create a class containing that information, to avoid needing the use of an ArrayList, but I don't know if this is an option.

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure about the uniqueness (they seem to be just concatenated first and last names with fixed max size). Also it is not apparent how having a `HashMap` helps putting the values into an array.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out using an appropriately designed `Object` rather than an `array` of such heterogeneous data (guessing they are `String`s in reality).

If you insist on keeping it the way you have though, you just need to allocate a new array with the size of the original `ArrayList` and iterate through, fetching the desired column. Assuming `ArrayList<String[]> list`

```
int size = list.size();
String[] firstColumn = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    firstColumn[i] = list.get(i)[0];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you can do 
`list.stream().map(array -> array[0].toString()).toArray()`